# Add CSS in Joomla after template CSS or before head close tag

Tags: css, joomla, stylesheet, joomla3.0, joomla-component

I developed a component for joomla 3.2 and I am [adding](http://docs.joomla.org/J3.x%3aAdding_JavaScript_and_CSS_to_the_page) a CSS file.

*my_component/views/my_view/tmpl/default.php*:

```
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addStyleSheet("components/my_component/static/css/my_css.css");
```

It works, it is loaded but "too early".

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="my_project/components/com_ciceron/static/css/styles.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="my_project/templates/business/font/mavenpro.css" type="text/css" />  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="my_project/templates/business/css/styles.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="my_project/templates/business/css/newStyles.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="my_project/templates/business/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="my_project/templates/business/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

As you can see the file that I add is added before template css, so some css rules are overwritten.

There is any way to add a CSS file after template CSS? or just before head close tag?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

This will not add the style sheet inside `head tag` but it adds under the `template css` , means from where ever you calling this method there it insert the style sheet. check the bottom [section](http://docs.joomla.org/J3.x%3aAdding_JavaScript_and_CSS_to_the_page)

```
$stylelink = '<!--[if lte IE 6]>' ."\n";
$stylelink .= '<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/IEonly.css" />' ."\n";
$stylelink .= '<![endif]-->' ."\n";

$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addCustomTag($stylelink);
```

Hope its works..